# phplist Database error #1193 - Unknown system variable 'set_path'

Tags: phplist

when i tried to install php list to localhost, in PHPMyadmin icant import database script, it gives this error "**#1193 - Unknown system variable 'set_path'** ", what should i do?

Sorrry for the bad English, Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi you should not import phplist database. Just create database, set this database name, mysql username & password in config.php file (find step 5) and follow installing phpList in a few steps:

1. Unpack the distribution files. Make sure to use "create directories"
   when unpacking.
2. This will create a directory called phplist-x.y.x where x.y.z is the
   version you unpacked.
3. In this directory, there will be a directory public_html which
   contains the directory lists. Upload the "lists" directory into a
   directory that can be accessed via the web. The rest of the files
   are for reference only and are not needed for phplist to work.
4. Create a database for phpList to use. phpList needs the name of that
   database during the installation process.
5. Configure phpList by opening the config.php file in the lists/config
   directory in your preferred text editor.
6. Go to the URL of the lists/admin directory of your phpList
   installation.

> Example If your website (lets say http://www.mysite.com) is mapped to
>   the directory /home/michael/www/, and you have uploaded the phpList
>   distribution files into /home/michael/www/lists/, then you should go
>   to: http://www.mysite.com/lists/admin/.